# How do I configure a port in my .conf file?

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc

This is what my conf file looks like:

```
prune=600
maxconnections=12
maxuploadtarget=20
rpcuser=user
rpcpassword=password
keypool=10000
server=1

[main]
rpcport=5040
```

Whenever I run this from the command line I get the following error:

> Binding RPC on address ::1 port 5040 failed.
>
> Binding RPC on address 127.0.0.1 port 5040 failed.

I checked for port 5040 using the `netstat -a` and it was listening, what's the problem?

Comment: Are you sure nothing else is using port 5040 already?

Comment: Please post the results of running
`sudo lsof -i | grep 5040`

Comment: My OS is Windows 10, not linux

Answer (score 1):

> Windows 10

Run `netstat -ab >file.txt` then `notepad file.txt` and search on `5040`. I suspect you will find `CDPSvc` immediately underneath - on my machine this "Connected Devices Platform Service" is already using your port.

If that's so, search on `5041`, then `5042` and continue up until search can't find it. That port is free: change your rpcport to match it.

Comment: Nothing happens when I run that command

Comment: There are two commands.

Comment: I don't quite understand, could you elaborate more?

Comment: 1/4: Open up an [Admin Command Prompt](https://superuser.com/a/968225)

Comment: 2/4: Type `netstat -ab >file.txt` into the Command Prompt, then press return. This is the first command and you do not expect something to happen: the `>file.txt` element tells Windows to save the ordinary output into a file in the current directory called `file.txt`. You're doing this because the ordinary output will overflow the Command Prompt buffer and you'll lose the initial output.

Comment: 3/4: Type `notepad file.txt` into the Command Prompt, then press return. This is the second command and you DO expect something to happen. [Microsoft notepad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Notepad) will appear with the `netstat -ab` output already within it.

Comment: 4/4: Using notepad, search on `5040` as described above.

Answer (score 1):

looks like 5040 already used, try to use default port or another port